# Unexpected module 'Ng2SmartTableModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, components, ng2-smart-table

I'm trying to learn ng2 smart table from this [link](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table) and i got this error.

Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'Ng2SmartTableModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Here is the app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  //templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  //template: `<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings"></ng2-smart-table>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  //title = 'app';
  settings = {
    columns: {
      id: {
        title: 'ID'
      },
      name: {
        title: 'Full Name'
      },
      username: {
        title: 'User Name'
      },
      email: {
        title: 'Email'
      }
    }
  };
}
```

And the app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Ng2SmartTableModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Can anyone help me fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it is a  module, You need to add inside **`imports`** not under **`declarations`**

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    Ng2SmartTableModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers :)